# How to add array values after exceeding a certain length in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to work out the best way to add array values when they exceed a certain length. The program will allow a user to input values into the array. Once the user enters the amount of numbers (can be as much as they want). The numbers should not exceed 6 columns, and if they do they should be added from right to left of the array. See below

The 12 numbers inputted by the user:

```
arrNumbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

A new array should be made which will look like this:

```
newArrNumbers = int [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Resulting in only 6 slots.

I have no idea on how to code this. I only know that this could be possible with an if statement like below. I am a beginner and would like to know a solution from someone experienced.

```
if (arrNumbers.length > 6)
```

Comment: How do you intend to sum the numbers? I'm not following the logic you're using to go from arrNumbers to newArrNumbers. 

Once you clarify that logic, I can implement the code.

Comment: "if they do they should be added from right to left of the array", can you explain what this means? if `arrNumbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3};`, what is your expected result? and what if `arrNumbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,1,2,3};` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this

```java
int[] arrNumbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[] res = new int[6];

// iterate over the initial array and chunk it. 6 will be our chunk per requirements.
for (int i = 0; i < arrNumbers.length; i += 6) {
    // create a sub array for the first 6 numbers.
    int[] ints = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrNumbers, i, Math.min(arrNumbers.length, i + 6));
    // add the first chunk to our resulting array. Repeat until needed.
    for (int j = 0; j < ints.length; j++) {
        res[j] += ints[j];
    }
}
```

Result: `res: {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}`

This will work for any array size for the `arrNumbers` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily iterate through the rest of Array.

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=6;i<arrNumbers.length;i++){
sum+=arrNumbers[i];
}
arrNumbers[5]=sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise and efficient answer:

```
    int[] arrNumbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int[] newArrNumbers = new int[6];

    for(int i  = 0; i < arrNumbers.length ; i++){
        newArrNumbers[i % 6] += arrNumbers[i];
    }
```

output: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]`